# Android - EditText in actionbar

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, android-edittext, action

I have an app and want to display an edittext field in the action bar at the top of the screen. Is it possible to do that? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use a custom layout for action bar as suggested by other answers. But let me add something.
Now that appCompat v21 is here, I would suggest you using [Toolbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html). It fulfills your purpose perfectly. And not to mention a new look and a lot of customizations. See this blog for more info

[AppCompat V21](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
//use this code to inflate your edittext   
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_title, null);
            final EditTexttext = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);


            getActionBar().setCustomView(v);
```

Comment: My app crashes when I start the application. (I am a beginner)

Comment: what error is coming..if you are using api level below 14 then you have to use getSupportActionbar().setCustomView(v);

Comment: I am using api 21. Is this good?:     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.blogspot.superthomaslab.smartbrowser/com.blogspot.superthomaslab.smartbrowser.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setCustomView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference

Comment: Yah it is good....for error...you can check the log cat in which java line the error is coming.

Comment: It crashes at the line: getActionBar().setCustomView(v);

Comment: //Try this   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
     .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

Comment: Still crashes, could you please post a whole mainactivity so I can look what's wrong?

Comment: //Put this code before inflating layout
  getActionBar().setIcon(null);
  getActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
  getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
  getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);